# Yandex карты. Достать стоимость доставки в поле input

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Как реализовать вывод информации балуна карты в поле `input`?

Часть кода:

```
ymaps.route([start, finish])
 .then(function (router) {
   var distance = Math.round(router.getLength() / 1000);
   message = '<span>Расстояние: ' + distance + 'км.</span><br/>' +
    '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: %sр.</span>';
```

Это расчет стоимости доставки.

Надо получить `"%sр"` в поле `input` (Пример: в балуне появилась стоимость доставки 1000, результат 1000 отправляем в поле.):

`input type="text" class="calk_delivery" name="delivery" id="delivery"`

для дальнейшей обработки (подсчет итоговой стоимости продукта, который высылается на почту пользователю после нажатия "Рассчитать")

Comment: Думаю, что нужно немного дополнить вопрос деталями. Например код вашего `input`. *получить "%sр" в поле input* - это значит заполнить инпут или получить из него значение, двояко звучит.

Comment: Заполнить поле (input) числом, полученным из балуна карты.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример изменения значения у `input`:

```js
function setInputValue(){
   var number = 1000; // значение, которе хотим установить
   var input = document.getElementById('delivery'); // получим нужный инпут по id
   input.value = number; // просто присвоим значение
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="calk_delivery" name="delivery" id="delivery"/>

<button onclick="setInputValue();"> Заполним числом инпут </button>
```

Если у вас есть значение, которое вы хотите вставить в `input`, то все что вам нужно - это воспользоваться приведенным примером. По поводу получения `"%sр"` - из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно откуда оно берется.

Comment: http://www.drova47.ru/calculator.html - если воспользоваться "Просмотр кода страницы" весь код видно.

Comment: как я понял у вас стоимость доставки расчитывается в `self.calculate(distance)`, ну вот как бы в примере нужно это подставить вместо `1000`.

Comment: Два варианта выходит, либо пусто и не получает данные, либо получает как текст, так и прописывает "self.calculate(distance)"

Comment: @rais-ja загляние в `calculate`, что-то у вас в `return` немного странное написано. Может там нужно тернарный оператор использовать `?:`?

Comment: Как в api карт яндекса написано так и применяю.

Comment: @rais-ja а попробуйте результат вывести в `console.log(number)`, а лучше напишите `debugger` внутри метода `calculate` и посмотрите, что у вас там происходит.

Comment: Решил с выводом данных. на данный момент выводит просто в <div id="">. Как заполнить данные в поле (input) без нажатия на кнопку

Comment: @rais-ja просто добавьте код к примеру внутрь `function (router) {...}` там где у вас получается значение `distance`, чтобы вычислить стоимость в методе `calculate` и поместить результат в переменную, к примеру `cost`, которую будете использовать для установки значения в `input` ну и в `span` тоже вы ее используете, просто нужно будет сделать как в `<span>Расстояние: ' + distance + 'км.</span>` без `replace` как вы делали. Чтобы было так: `<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + cost + 'р.</span>`